# Rotate CCSprite to touch in Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently using this code to rotate a CCSprite (player) object to face the last touch. The problem is this makes the rotation pretty jumpy, and it doesn't look very smooth.

```
CGPoint playerPos = [player position];
CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x-lastPoint.x, currentPoint.y-lastPoint.y);
CGPoint playerNewPos = ccpAdd(playerPos, diff);
[player setRotation:-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(playerNewPos.y-playerPos.y, playerNewPos.x-playerPos.x))];
```

How could I make this code more smooth and fluid?

I've also tried using CCRotateTo but it's causing the same issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
float angle = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(playerNewPos.y-playerPos.y, playerNewPos.x-playerPos.x));
id action=[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:1.0 angle:angle];
[player runAction:[CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here get Old and New Touch Position as below

```
- (void)registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:
           self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

     NSLog(@"touch end ==%f-----%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);

    // Save old location to NSuserDefault And get new From Above

}
```

Now Rotate according to Position as below

```
int offX = (CurrentTouch.x - OldTouch.x);
int offY = (CurrentTouch.y - OldTouch.y));

float angleRadians = atanf((float)offX / (float)offY);
float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);

id action=[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:1.0 angle:angleDegrees];
[player runAction:action];
```